# How do I prevent this infinite loop triggered by setting state via onChange in a controlled select element?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

### **UPDATE**: I noticed that when I made the "iPay" state its own separate state instead of including it in the bill state object that the infinite loop issue went away. I have no idea why that is. I am still new to react and very new to the concept of putting state into complex objects instead of making a lot of individual state. Can anyone explain to me why that is?

In order to determine how to allocate the debt in my bill splitting exercise, I have decided to use a select element with an option of "you" or "peer". A state object contains the state that determines the calculation (based off the select value)

My issue is that when I set the select value to the state needed and then use the setter function in the callback to onChange to set the state to the current select value, I get an infinite loop. When I console.log the target value I noticed that if I put a value for my select element then the screen never changes to the newly selected option. If I use a defaultValue then it does, but I need it to be a controlled input.

I wrote an explicit comment around my problem area (towards the bottom of the component, inside the return), but will include the entire App component in case the context is needed

```
import "./App.css";
// components
import { PeerCard } from "./components/PeerCard/PeerCard";
import { BillRow } from "./components/BillRow/BillRow";
import { AddPeer } from "./components/AddPeer/AddPeer";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const staticPeers = [
    {
      name: "Clark",
      // id: 0,
      money: -7,
      selected: false,
      profilePic:
        "https://kevindayphotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/headshot-for-business-man-1200x675.jpg",
    },
    {
      name: "Sarah",
      // id: 1,
      money: 27,
      selected: true,
      profilePic:
        "https://www.cityheadshots.com/uploads/5/1/2/1/5121840/editor/lowres-mjb-5074_3.jpg?1574008349",
    },
    {
      name: "Anthony",
      // id: 2,
      money: 0,
      selected: false,
      profilePic:
        "https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/54693b1ee4b07c8a3da7b6d0/1492201646122-7CCYPRAF33QU2MGPW8YJ/Headshot-by-Lamonte-G-Photography-Baltimore-Corporate-Headshot-Photographer-IMG_6763-Edit.JPG?format=1500w",
    },
  ];
  const [selectFriend, setSelectFriend] = useState(1);
  const [peers, setPeers] = useState(staticPeers);
  const [bill, setBill] = useState({
    totalBill: 0,
    myExpense: 0,
    iPay: "you",
  });

  let peerBill = bill.totalBill - bill.myExpense;

  const onSelectFriend = (index) => {
    setSelectFriend(index);
    if (selectFriend === index) setSelectFriend(null);
  };

  const onAddPeer = (peerName, peerPic) => {
    if (peerName && peerPic)
      setPeers([
        ...peers,
        {
          name: peerName,
          money: 0,
          selected: false,
          profilePic: peerPic,
        },
      ]);
  };
  // using Object.assign to modify the money state of the selected Friend
  /*

! Calcs are decided based upon the who pays state, this state will be toggled in the select below
*/
  const handleMoney = () => {
    if (bill.iPay === "you")
      setPeers(
        peers.map((i, index) =>
          index === selectFriend
            ? Object.assign(i, { ...i, money: i.money + peerBill })
            : { ...i }
        )
      );
  };
  if (bill.iPay === "peer")
    setPeers(
      peers.map((i, index) =>
        index === selectFriend
          ? Object.assign(i, { ...i, money: i.money - peerBill })
          : { ...i }
      )
    );

  // ! infinite loop caused by setting state with the onChange event
  // waiting for answer from forum to proceed here

  // const handleWhoPays = (e, id) => {
  //   const selectTag = document.getElementById(id);

  //   if(selectTag.value === )
  //   setBill({...bill, iPay: e.target.value})

  // };


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="peer-container">
        {peers.map((i, index) => {
          return (
            <PeerCard
              // key={index}
              handleSelectFriend={onSelectFriend}
              peers={peers}
              index={index}
              name={i.name}
              money={i.money}
              selected={selectFriend}
              profilePic={i.profilePic}
            />
          );
        })}

        <AddPeer handleAddPeer={onAddPeer} />
        <button className="mt4" id="close-btn">
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="bill-total-container">
        {peers.map((i, index) => {
          // this will likely change
          if (index === selectFriend)
            return (
              <>
                <h1 className="mt3 mb3">Split a bill with {i.name}</h1>
                <BillRow>
                  <span>Bill value</span>
                  <input
                    onChange={(e) =>
                      setBill({
                        ...bill,
                        totalBill: Number(e.target.value),
                      })
                    }
                    type="number"
                    id="bill-value"
                  />
                </BillRow>
                <BillRow>
                  <span>Your Expense</span>
                  <input
                    onChange={(e) =>
                      setBill({
                        ...bill,
                        myExpense: Number(e.target.value),
                      })
                    }
                    type="number"
                    id="your-expense"
                  />
                </BillRow>
                <BillRow>
                  <span>{i.name}'s Expense</span>
                  <input value={peerBill} type="text" id="thier-expense" />
                </BillRow>




 {/* !!! THIS IS THE PROBLEM AREA !!! */}
                <BillRow>
                  <span>Who is paying the bill?</span>
                  <select
                    name={bill.iPay}
                    value={bill.iPay}
                    onChange={(e) =>
                      // console.log(e.target.value)
                      setBill({ ...bill, iPay: e.target.value })
                    }
                    style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                    id="who-pays"
                  >
                    {/* <option ></option> */}
                    <option value="you">You</option>
                    <option value="peer">{i.name}</option>
                  </select>
                </BillRow>
{/* !!! THIS IS THE PROBLEM AREA !!! */}


                <div className="split-bill-container">
                  <button onClick={handleMoney}>Split Bill</button>
                </div>
              </>
            );
        })}
        {selectFriend === null && (
          <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            Select a Friend to Split the Bill With!
          </h1>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the BillRow component, all it does is render the children

```
export const BillRow = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div className='bill-row-container mt3 mb3'>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I would like to know how I can set the state to the currently selected value of the select element without an infinite loop or unnecessary re-renders

[My github repository](https://github.com/cassius2828/eat-n-split) 
[Hosted Site](https://eat-n-build-28.netlify.app/)

I have also tried e.preventDefault in the onChange, but it was to no avail